# calculating aspect ratio for a legal paper(8.5x14")

Tags: printer, aspect-ratio

I have a PDF(28x17") which I print using the landscape mode in a legal(8.5x14") paper. But this effectively reduces the font size by 50%. What size should I choose for the PDF if I would like the font size to be atleast 75%?. 
I have the following constraints on width/height of the PDF.

1)Width may be increased further(28+) but not decreased below 28

2)Height may be decreased/increased.(decreased not less than 9")

Is there any way to increase the font size in the paper?

Comment: I don't get your question.  If you want the font size to be 75%, and you want to maintain the aspect ratio, you need to print the document on 21 x 12.75" paper.

Comment: @Breakthrough: Unfortunately, the paper should be a legal. So that is not an option. However the aspect ratio can be adjusted by adjusting the width/height of the PDF with above constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Your PDF document matches the legal paper aspect ratio. 28x17 is exactly twice 8.5x14, thus: if you print your document on a single piece of Legal, you will have to scale it down to 50%.

Now, mathematically, there is really nothing you can do to make the font size any larger without eliminating content from the larger PDF whilst still maitaining aspect ratio.

If your PDF were, say, 20x17, you could theoretically try and rduce the height of the document so that the proportions were met. If you do the math, WIDTH = 0.6 X HEIGHT.

Answer (score 0):

Aspect ratio is fixed. It is the width divided by the heighth (or vice versa, so long as you are consistant). The aspect ratio of 8.5"x14" is the same as the aspect ratio of 17"x28". Multiple 8.5 and 14 by 2 and you get 17 and 28, respectively.

Manipulating the aspect ratio will only skew the text and make it look odd and difficult to read, which is probably not what you wish to do with a legal document.

The only way you can adjust the size of the text in this document given the restrictions you have, is by modifying the Page Scaling, and in Page Setup, the margins. Changes made this way will not skew the text, so it'll be legible. However, they are very limited in that there is only so much you can do to adjust margins before you run out of page.